# How does Spring interpolate ${x} inside a string?

Tags: java, spring, string-interpolation

I have a java class in a Spring project that looks (edited) like:

```
@Component
public class X
{
private static final ApplicationContext CTX = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("file:${PATH}/ApplicationContext.xml");
...
```

I am looking for the reference explaining how the ${PATH} is interpolated in the string parameter. The PATH is passed as a system property ( java -DPATH=...) so I assume it takes it from there but I can't find an explanation describing the mechanism. Is it a Spring related feature similar to the syntax  used in @Value?

Comment: Starting without the system property gives an exception: `Could not resolve placeholder 'PATH' in value "file:${PATH}/ApplicationContext.xml"
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser` so it is Spring related but I still don't find info on that in the Spring doc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`configLocations` (type `String`) passed to one of the [`FileSystemXmlApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.html) constructors are processed by the [`resolvePath()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.html#resolvePath-java.lang.String-) method inherited from the [`AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.html) class.

`resolvePath()` documentation says:

> Resolve the given path, replacing placeholders with corresponding environment property values if necessary. Applied to config locations.
>
> **See Also:**
> [`PropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(String)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html#resolveRequiredPlaceholders-java.lang.String-)

`resolveRequiredPlaceholders()` documentation says:

> Resolve `${...}` placeholders in the given text, replacing them with corresponding property values as resolved by [`getProperty(java.lang.String)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-). Unresolvable placeholders with no default value are ignored and passed through unchanged.

The [`PropertyResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html) declaring that `getProperty()` method is actually a [`StandardEnvironment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/StandardEnvironment.html).

`StandardEnvironment` documentation says:

> [`Environment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) implementation suitable for use in 'standard' (i.e. non-web) applications.
>
> In addition to the usual functions of a [`ConfigurableEnvironment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment.html) such as property resolution and profile-related operations, this implementation configures two default property sources, to be searched in the following order:
>
> - [system properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/AbstractEnvironment.html#getSystemProperties--)
> - [system environment variables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/AbstractEnvironment.html#getSystemEnvironment--)

Comment: All this can only be understood by checking the source code, the documentation is severely lacking.